# TYPO3 felogin plugin has no CSS

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

Whatever I tried, could not make Felogin plugin look like (bootstrap) other form elements.

I also tried to use "Feature Toggles" and set Felogin: extbase on Enable.

BTW the Permalogin function is also not working.

I'm a new to Typo3! Please help.

This is what I have regarding the form style:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: if you use the Extbase version of felogin, the template used can be changed using the TypoScript constant styles.content.loginform.templateFile AFAICS

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the outcome you described:
[templateFile] = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin/FrontendLogin.html

But nothing is changing. So the Login form has not the same style as I have with contact form and indexed search e.g.

Comment: You should be more clear with what you need help. Do you want bootstrap HTML (which does not need any additional CSS then) or do you miss any CSS?

Comment: I guess you checked with TSOB that you checked that styles.content.loginform.templateFile = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin/FrontendLogin.html, right? first, is it actually used? try to modify it (you should not do that, but it is just for a test ;) ) and see if your change is visible. I suspect that "Feature Toggles" >  Felogin: extbase interfere with that (just a guess, IDK if is true)

Comment: The "extbase" feature toggle would enable the (more modern) Fluid templates (https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/commit/4c1848d80e8e58e1006a4bd268de0b4d13100aca). But those are not styled for the Bootstrap CSS frameworks, too. But it's probably a better start to use them and adapt to your needs.

Comment: bootstrap_package does only include the marker templates yet.

Comment: Thank you guys, the template is indeed not so modern. Anything I try to change for example EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin/FrontendLogin.html. Noting is changed. Nothing happens. The "extbase" feature toggle is also not working. I'm still wondering why I cannot see  the login form style like it is in contact forms e.g.

Comment: Just updated the question with screenshots for more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to know that both templates for pibase and extbase/fluid are located in `EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/`. File `FrontendLogin.html` is for pibase only and contains all views. For extabse/fluid you have different files for different views, where login form is `EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/Login/Login.html` and so on.

Copy `Login/Login.html` to your custom sitepackage. E.g. `typo3conf/ext/custom_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin/Login.html`.
Then you should configure it via TypoScript

```
plugin.tx_felogin_login {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:custom_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin
    }
}
```

Adjust your `Login/Login.html` to your requirements, f.x. for TwitterBootstrap 4

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:flashMessages />
<f:if condition="{cookieWarning}">
    <f:render partial="CookieWarning" />
</f:if>
<f:switch expression="{messageKey}">
    <f:case value="welcome"><f:variable name="alertKey" value="info" /></f:case>
    <f:case value="error"><f:variable name="alertKey" value="danger" /></f:case>
    <f:defaultCase><f:variable name="alertKey" value="info" /></f:defaultCase>
</f:switch>
<f:if condition="{messageKey}">
    <div class="alert alert-{alertKey}" role="alert">
        <h3>
            <f:render partial="RenderLabelOrMessage" arguments="{key: '{messageKey}_header'}" />
        </h3>
        <p>
            <f:render partial="RenderLabelOrMessage" arguments="{key: '{messageKey}_message'}" />
        </p>
    </div>
</f:if>
<f:if condition="{onSubmit}">
    <f:then>
        <f:form target="_top" fieldNamePrefix="" action="login" onsubmit="{onSubmit}">
            <f:render section="content" arguments="{_all}" />
        </f:form>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <f:form target="_top" fieldNamePrefix="" action="login">
            <f:render section="content" arguments="{_all}" />
        </f:form>
    </f:else>
</f:if>

<f:if condition="{settings.showForgotPassword}">
    <f:link.action action="recovery" controller="PasswordRecovery">
        <f:render partial="RenderLabelOrMessage" arguments="{key: 'forgot_header'}" />
    </f:link.action>
</f:if>

<f:section name="content">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <f:translate key="login" />
        </legend>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-form-label">
                <f:translate key="username" />
            </label>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                <f:form.textfield name="user" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-form-label">
                <f:translate key="password" />
            </label>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                <f:form.password name="pass" data="{rsa-encryption: ''}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <f:if condition="{permaloginStatus} > -1">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-form-label"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <f:if condition="{permaloginStatus} == 1">
                            <f:then>
                                <f:form.hidden name="permalogin" value="0" additionalAttributes="{disabled: 'disabled'}" />
                                <f:form.checkbox name="permalogin" id="permalogin" value="1" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input" />
                            </f:then>
                            <f:else>
                                <f:form.hidden name="permalogin" value="0" />
                                <f:form.checkbox name="permalogin" id="permalogin" value="1" class="custom-control-input" />
                            </f:else>
                        </f:if>
                        <label for="permalogin" class="custom-control-label">
                            <f:translate id="permalogin" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </f:if>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10 ml-auto">
                <f:form.submit value="{f:translate(key: 'login')}" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="felogin-hidden">
            <f:form.hidden name="logintype" value="login" />
            <f:form.hidden name="pid" value="{storagePid}" />
            <f:if condition="{redirectURL}!=''">
                <f:form.hidden name="redirect_url" value="{redirectURL}" />
            </f:if>
            <f:if condition="{referer}!=''">
                <f:form.hidden name="referer" value="{referer}" />
            </f:if>
            <f:if condition="{redirectReferrer}!=''">
                <f:form.hidden name="redirectReferrer" value="off" />
            </f:if>
            <f:if condition="{noRedirect}!=''">
                <f:form.hidden name="noredirect" value="1" />
            </f:if>
            {extraHidden}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</f:section>

</html>
```

Comment: To get permalogin working you need additionally  `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['permalogin']` set.

Comment: Minor detail: In  TYPO3 10+, `felogin` is actually located in  subdir (`public/typo3/sysext`),  not the `public/typo3conf/ext` subdir. -- If you want the example phrase consistent with your first TypoScript block  you should say _Copy `Login/Login.html` to your custom sitepackage. E.g. `typo3conf/ext/custom_sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Felogin/Login/Login.html. `_

Comment: Rephrased my description to match typoscript, thx for your hint